# Each ou next a partir de uma query MySQL

Tags: php, jquery

Como fazer o post do próximo item em uma query MySQL de vários itens?

Quando mudar `$( ".membro" ).change(function() {` ) enviar os dados do próximo `$("membro")` para o arquivo `membros.php`, via `$.post`.

**[JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QkH5X/1/)**

JS:

```
$(".membro").change(function () {    
    $.post("membros.php", {
        mes: $(".mes").val(),
        ano: $(".ano").val(),
        celula: $(".celulanome").val(),
        membro: $(".membro").val()
    });    
});
```

HTML

```
<tr class=\"tabl\">
    <td id=\"tabela2\" class=\"id\">$row[posicao]
    </td>
    <td id=\"tabela4a\">
    <input type=\"hidden\"  class=\"celulanome\" name=\"membro\" value=\"$celula\">
    <input type=\"hidden\"  class=\"mes\" name=\"membro\" value=\"$mes\">
    <input type=\"hidden\"  class=\"ano\" name=\"membro\" value=\"$ano\">
    <input type=\"text\"  class=\"membro\" name=\"membro\" value=\"$row[membro]\">
    </td>
</tr>


<tr class=\"tabl\">
    <td id=\"tabela2b\" class=\"id2\">$row[posicao]
    </td>
    <td id=\"tabela4b\">
    <input type=\"hidden\"  class=\"celulanome\" name=\"membro\" value=\"$celula\">
    <input type=\"hidden\"  class=\"mes\" name=\"membro\" value=\"$mes\">
    <input type=\"hidden\"  class=\"ano\" name=\"membro\" value=\"$ano\">
    <input type=\"text\"  class=\"membro\" name=\"membro\" value=\"$row[membro]\">
    </td>
</tr>


<tr class=\"tabl\">
    <td id=\"tabela2c\" class=\"id3\">$row[posicao]
    </td>
    <td id=\"tabela4c\">
    <input type=\"hidden\"  class=\"celulanome\" name=\"membro\" value=\"$celula\">
    <input type=\"hidden\"  class=\"mes\" name=\"membro\" value=\"$mes\">
    <input type=\"hidden\"  class=\"ano\" name=\"membro\" value=\"$ano\">
    <input type=\"text\"  class=\"membro\" name=\"membro\" value=\"$row[membro]\">
    </td>
</tr>
```

PHP

```
<?php    
include "bd_connect.php";

$membro=$_POST['membro'];    
$celula=$_POST['celula'];
$mes=$_POST['mes'];
$ano=$_POST['ano'];
$posicao=$_POST['posicao'];

if (isset($membro))
{
   $query = mysql_query("UPDATE contas2 SET membro='$membro' WHERE mes LIKE '$mes' AND ano LIKE '$ano' AND celula LIKE '$celula'") or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: Podes explicar melhor o que queres dizer com "fazer o post do proximo item"?

Comment: quando o input muda (  $( ".membro" ).change(function() {  ) ele envia os dados para o arquivo membros.php ($.post)

Comment: Sim, isso eu consigo ver no c«odigo mas o que está a faltar?

Comment: como eu enviou o valor da proxima class "membro", quando mudar o proximo input

Comment: Então quando `$( ".membro" ).change(function() {` for acionado queres mandao não isto `membro: $( ".membro" ).val()` mas o valor do próximo membro?

Comment: @Sergio isso mesmo!!!

Answer (score 2):

Teste assim:

```
$(".membro").change(function () {
    var proximoMembro = $(this).closest('tr').next().find('.membro');
    $.post("membros.php", {
        mes: $(".mes").val(),
        ano: $(".ano").val(),
        celula: $(".celulanome").val(),
        membro: proximoMembro.val()
    });

});
```

A idea é:

- `$(this)` ponto de partida, o "membro" que mudou
- `.closest('tr')` procurar subindo na arvore DOM o primeiro `tr`
- `.next()` ir para o proximo `tr`
- `.find('.membro');` descer/procurar dentro dessa linha o elemento com a classe `.membro`

Comment: não funcionou!!! usei o código exatamente como colocou ai!

Comment: pode explicar melhor o que não funcionou? recebeu os dados errados do lado do php ou nem sequer recebeu dados no php? algum erro na consola?

Comment: @AlanPS vi agora que tem muitos campos com o nome `membro`. Isso vai dar problemas no php, devia pelo menos ter `name="membro[]"` para receber um array no php.

Comment: não envia valor nenhum!!

Comment: como sabe que não envia? viu na consola ou o php não responde? pode colocar o seu php também?

Comment: coloquei meu php!

Comment: @AlanPS coloca na primeira linha do php `var_dump($_POST);` e diz-me o que te dá. Entretanto, aliás antes disso, tens de corrigir no HTML para os nomes (`name=""`) de cada input ser o correto. No PHP tens `$mes=$_POST['mes'];` mas não há nenhum input com `name="mes"` ...

Comment: o php funciona perfeitamente, o erro é no js, pois se eu deixar o cód antigo ele funciona no primeiro input!

Comment: Já corrigiu os problemas de HTML que indiquei em cima? Tem o site online para eu poder ver?

Comment: Já corrigi sim, na verdade faz parte de uma área restrita do site e não dá pra mostrar, mas vou tentar pesquisar melhor o problema!

Comment: adicionei um jsfiddle no post!!

Comment: o resultado do alert é undefined e não o valor que eu digitei no input!

Answer (score 0):

Consegui usando each e find!!!

Código:

```
$(".membro").change(function () {
$('.tabl').each(function() {
var proximoMembro = $(this).find( ".membro" ).val();

    $.post("membros.php", {
        mes: $(".mes").val(),
        ano: $(".ano").val(),
        celula: $(".celulanome").val(),
        membro: proximoMembro
    });

});
});
```